# Hibernate generates SQL query with keyword 'as' for table, which generates ORA-00933 in Oracle 12c

Tags: hibernate, jpa, oracle12c

I have the following code:

```java
@Stateless
public class UsersStore {
    public User getUserByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password) {
        if (username == null || password == null) {
            return null;
        }

        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactoryInstance().openSession()) {

            final Query<User> query = session.createQuery(
                    "select u from User u where u.username = :username and u.password = :password", User.class);

            query.setParameter("username", username);
            query.setParameter("password", password);

            return query.getSingleResult();
        }

    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HARPIA_USER")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @NotNull
    private String username;
    @NotNull
    private String password;

    public User(String username, String password) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

The code above generates the following SQL:

`select u1_0.id, u1_0.password, u1_0.username from HARPIA_USER as u1_0 where u1_0.username = ? and u1_0.password = ?`

This SQL generates `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`. The reason for that is, Oracle does not accept `AS` keyword for table, at least the version I have, Oracle 12c.

Is that any workaround to solve that issue. Can I tell hibernate to omit the `AS` keyword? And by removing I am not telling to get rid of the aliases.

Hibernate version: 6.0.0.Alpha4

Comment: Are you u sure this was generated by Oracle dialect?

Comment: Yes. At least is what I can see in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default Hibernate behavior is case insensitive, but Oracle is default UPPERCASE sensitive, so try set parameters in uppercase

**UPD**

firstly try to change property names to uppercase in the query, but honestly, it really depends on you Ora settings

Comment: The parameters are being set correctly. What this has to do with 'as' keyword?

Comment: just try `select u from User u where u.USERNAME = :username and u.PASSWORD = :password", User.class`
by the way: what is a User entity name? Can you share a User class?

Comment: If I use this query you posted, I will get an exception tell me 'Cannot resolve path (`USERNAME`) relative to `NavigablePath', which makes totally sense, as this  uppercase property does not exists in User class. I guess you did not get my question. The issue in the  query generated is only the 'as' keyword, I need to get rid of it to make the query working in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Issue went way after I downgraded the Hibernate version to 5.4.12.Final.